# Errors in Eclipse when Creating Instances Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am taking Learning Java online on Lynda.com and what we are supposed to do is to create a Car Object. Here is the code for the Car class below:

```
import java.awt.*; // abstract window toolkit library


public class Car {

double avgMilesPerGallon;
String licensePlate;
Color paintColor;
boolean lightsWorking;

// Constructor
    public Car(double inputAverageMPG, String inputLicensePlate, 
            Color inputPaintColor, boolean inputTaillightsWorking ) {
        this.avgMilesPerGallon = inputAverageMPG;
        this.licensePlate = inputLicensePlate;
        this.paintColor = inputPaintColor;
        this.lightsWorking = inputTaillightsWorking;

    } 

    }
```

And this is the code for my Main class (I named it CrimsonPeak):

```
import java.awt.*;

public class CrimsonPeak {
 public static void main(String[] args) {



     Car myCar = new Car( inputAverageMPG: 25.5, inputLicensePlate: "1BC32E",
             inputPaintColor: Color.BLUE, inputTaillightsWorking: true);

     Car erikaCar = new Car( inputAverageMPG: 13.9, inputLicensePlate: "3D20CE", 
             Color.BLACK, inputTaillightsWorking: false);




 }

}
```

I was following everything that the video on Lynda.com was showing me, but I still get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
inputAverageMPG cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
inputLicensePlate cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
inputPaintColor cannot be resolved
Syntax error on token ":", :: expected
inputTaillightsWorking cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
inputAverageMPG cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
inputLicensePlate cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
Color cannot be resolved to a variable
inputTaillightsWorking cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
at CrimsonPeak.main(CrimsonPeak.java:11)
```

Any idea of how I can fix the aforementioned errors? I tried to understand it from the video from Lynda.com but I can't seem to find what is causing the errors.

Also, the video on Lynda.com was showing the walkthrough of the above code on Intellij IDEA 2017.  Could that also be a reason to why I'm getting the above errors on Eclipse?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is no need to pass inputAverageMPG in car class just pass the value , `new Car( 25.5,  "1BC32E",
              Color.BLUE,  true);` , Also you need constructor to assign the passed value in Car class

Comment: Java has no labels in constructors http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Car, you don't have to do `inputAverageMPG: 25.5, inputLicensePlate: "1BC32E"`, and so on. It's just `25.5,"1BC32E"`. Remove the `inputAverageMPG:`, `inputLicensePlate:`, and anywhere else in the constructors where you did that.

```
Car myCar = new Car(25.5,"1BC32E", Color.BLUE, true);

Car erikaCar = new Car(13.9, "3D20CE", Color.BLACK, false);
```

It should look like that. If the tutorial on Lynda.com told you to put those in there, find a different site.

Comment: I did what you explained, and that corrected the error.

Comment: @ForbiddenKraken Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. And welcome to StackOverflow :)